# Extract data from the nested parenthesis in bash

Tags: text-processing, perl, csv

I'd need a way to extract certain data and store it in file for auditing and migration. 
Here's my data look like.

```
network vlan internal-vlan {
    description "internal-use"
    interfaces {
        1.1 { }
        1.2 { }
    }
    MTU {
    1500
    }
}
network vlan external-vlan {
    description "external-use"
    interfaces {
       2.1 { }
       2.2 { }
    }
    MTU {
    1500
    }
}
```

I need to extract the vlan names and its descriptions and its interface details in a table format, something like below. If I could a bash script or maybe perl to run through this data file, I'll generate the output in a csv file and could open it for auditing.

[image]

**Updating the input data & requirement (SORRY),** if you notice there is a dummy vlan which does not have MTU, in that I want the MTU columns value to be none.

```
network vlan internal-vlan {
    description "internal-use"
    interfaces {
        1.1 { }
        1.2 { }
    }
    MTU {
    1500
    }
}
network vlan external-vlan {
    description "external-use"
    interfaces {
       2.1 { }
       2.2 { }
    }
    MTU {
    1500
    }
}
network vlan dummy-vlan {
    description "dummy-use"
    interfaces {
       1.1 { }
    }
}
network interface 1.1 {
    Status {
        UP
    }
}
network interface 1.2 {
    Status {
        UP
    }
}
network interface 2.1 {
    Status {
        DOWN
    }
}
network interface 2.2 {
    Status {
        UP
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a perfect use for [Tcl](https://www.tcl.tk) -- that data is valid Tcl syntax, so we just need to define a `network` function and we have a valid DSL:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

proc network {_ name data} {
    set values [lmap val [concat $name [dict values $data]] {
        format {"%s"} [regsub -all {\s+} [string trim $val] " "]
    }]
    puts [join $values ,]
}

puts {"Vlan","Description","Interfaces","MTU"}
source [lindex $argv 0]
```

then

```
$ tclsh parse.tcl datafile
"Vlan","Description","Interfaces","MTU"
"internal-vlan","internal-use","1.1 { } 1.2 { }","1500"
"external-vlan","external-use","2.1 { } 2.2 { }","1500"
```

Or install [tcllib](https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcllib/) to let it handle the CSV output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require csv

proc network {_ name data} {
    puts [csv::join [lmap val [concat $name [dict values $data]] {
        regsub -all {\s+} [string trim $val] " "
    }]]
}

puts [csv::join {Vlan Description Interfaces MTU}]
source [lindex $argv 0]
```

```
$ tclsh parse.tcl datafile
Vlan,Description,Interfaces,MTU
internal-vlan,internal-use,1.1 { } 1.2 { },1500
external-vlan,external-use,2.1 { } 2.2 { },1500
```

---

For the older Tcl 8.5 version, add this proc to the top of the program:

```
proc lmap {varname list body} {
    upvar 1 $varname element
    set result {}
    foreach element $list {
        lappend result [uplevel 1 $body]
    }
    return $result
}
```

---

To handle different network types, as well as the "none" value, and also to ensure the fields are in the right order:

```
proc network {type name data} {
    if {$type ne "vlan"} {
        return
    }
    set values [list $name]
    foreach key {description interfaces MTU} {
        set val [expr {[dict exists $data $key] ? [dict get $data $key] : "none"}]
        lappend values [regsub -all {\s+} [string trim $val] " "]
    }
    puts [join $values ,]
}
```

Comment: thank you. But its failing, 
`"Vlan","Description","Interfaces","MTU"
invalid command name "lmap"
    while executing
"lmap val [concat $name [dict values $data]] {
        format {"%s"} [regsub -all {\s+} [string trim $val] " "]
    }"
    (procedure "network" line 2)
    invoked from within
"network vlan internal-vlan {
    description "internal-use"
    interfaces {
        1.1 { }
        1.2 { }
    }
        MTU {
        1500
        ..."
    (file "datafile" line 1)
    invoked from within
"source [lindex $argv 0]"
    (file "parse.tcl" line 10)`

Comment: You have an older Tcl version. I'll update shortly.

Comment: awesome, that did the trick mate. Appreciate your help. But i see the every line output is having double quotes, so i made `{"%s"}` to `{%s}`. But Glenn, If my input data file has multiple other functions i think this procedure would fail, isn't it. This would work, provided the data input has network vlan and vlan name, but if it has more like network interface number and its own nested loop, this would fail isn't it. Please check my latest input file.

Comment: Thank you so much Glenn, big hugs :) I see the return being called to stop further processing. What if there's other functions instead of network, in my data file I have network function and some other like, system, auth at the top of the file and at the bottom of the file. I was thinking to take out the remaining of the network functions with a sed or head or tail commands, but was thinking can we make the proc network to trigger when it sees network loop and others to be skipped.

Comment: You keep adding features, don't you? Time to ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry Glenn. I just got excited. Sure let me put a new thread. Appreciate your support so far.

Comment: In case anyone on future is looking for its continuation - [Extract data from multiple nested parenthesis in TCL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580385/extract-data-from-multiple-nested-parenthesis-in-tcl)

Answer (score 1):

If your input data are uniform, you can try something like the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw{ say };

say 'Vlan,Description,Interfaces,MTU';
my @interfaces;
while (<>) {
    if (/(?|network vlan (.*) \{|description (".*"))/) {
        print "$1,";
    } elsif (/interfaces/) {
        @interfaces = ();
    } elsif (/ *(.* \{ \})/) {
        push @interfaces, "$1";
    } elsif (/MTU \{/) {
        my $next = <>;
        say "@interfaces,$1" if $next =~ /^ *(.*)/;
    }
}
```

If more variation in the data is allowed (i.e. the newlines are optional), you'll have to write a real parser.

Comment: thank you for helping. But the data are not uniform, there will be more nested loops in some and less in others.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the configuration file format is similar for all configs :
Using **awk** :

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { printf "Vlan,descripton,interfaces,MTU\n" }
{
if ($1 ~ /^network/ ) { printf $3","; }
if ( $1 ~ /description/ ) { printf $2","; }
if ( $1 ~ /^[0-9]\.[0-9]/ ) { printf $1$2$3" "; }
if ( $1 ~ /^[0-9]{2,}/ ) { printf ","$1"\n"; }
} ' input.conf
Vlan,descripton,interfaces,MTU
internal-vlan,"internal-use",1.1{} 1.2{} ,1500
external-vlan,"external-use",2.1{} 2.2{} ,1500
```

Comment: thanks, but format differs. in some network vlan configuration, there wont be any interfaces assigned.

Comment: did u try ?what is the output it shows

Comment: Yes it gives the same output as yours. But i think this may not work effectively with my full data input file. As there would be cases where there is no description for a function set and in that I need to put value as none. I see we are looking for network and description keywords, but for interface block if I just have 1 interface configured, then this is failing. Similarly if i have another network block without interface and just MTU in it, its messing everything up.