# Extract data from multiple nested parenthesis in TCL

Tags: text-processing, tcl

I need another help, this is in continuation of [Extract data from the nested parenthesis in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580031/extract-data-from-the-nested-parenthesis-in-bash),

I have input data like below with multiple blocks, I want to put a logic to check for network vlans block alone, exclude the auths, network trunk, network interface blocks.

```
auths remote {
    roles {
        admin {
            role administrator
        }
        readonly {
            role read-only
        }
    }
}

auths ldap system { 
    login-attribute uid
    port 636
}

network vlan internal-vlan {
    description "internal-use"
    interfaces {
        1.1 { }
        1.2 { }
    }
    MTU {
    1500
    }
}
network vlan external-vlan {
    description "external-use"
    interfaces {
       2.1 { }
       2.2 { }
    }
    MTU {
    1500
    }
}
network vlan dummy-vlan {
    description "dummy-use"
    interfaces {
       1.1 { }
    }
}

network trunk {
    description "none"
}

network interface 1.1 {
    Status {
        UP
    }
}
network interface 1.2 {
    Status {
        UP
    }
}
network interface 2.1 {
    Status {
        DOWN
    }
}
network interface 2.2 {
    Status {
        UP
    }
}
system update settings {
    frequency monthly
}
```

I want similar output as before. I think I have to make a parent function and put a if logic to check if the block starts with "network vlan" then trigger the proc network.

If I can put a if logic to check for string "network vlan" and then trigger a proc, i think i can relate for rest of configs and create new functions wherever needed.

Comment: You'll want to get familiar with the Tcl language: [it only has 12 syntax rules](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm). There's a [tutorial](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) and [other learning material](https://tcl.tk/about/)

Comment: In this case, you'll want to use [the `unknown` command](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/unknown.htm) to ignore things like "system"

Answer (score 1):

Since your last question asked for perl solutions, here is one that is fairly simple, except for the recursive regular expression needed to match nested `{...}` blocks, which I have separated out into the variable `$balanced`. This also allows it to be used 3 times, once to match the block after each of the keywords `network vlan`, `interfaces`, and `MTU`.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
open(F,"datafile") or die;
my $data = join("",<F>);
my $balanced = qr/
 (    ( [^{}]*+
        ({     (?-2)*   })?
      )*
 )/x;
while($data =~ m/network\s+vlan\s+([^ {]+)\s*{$balanced}/g){
    my $vlan = $1;
    my $body = $2;
    $body =~ m/description\s*("[^\"]*")/;
    my $desc = $1;
    $body =~ m/interfaces\s*{$balanced}/;
    my $intf = $1;
    $intf =~ s/\s+/ /g;
    my $mtu = 'none';
    $mtu = $1  if($body =~ m/MTU\s*{$balanced}/);
    $mtu =~ s/\s+/ /g;
    print "$vlan, $desc,$intf,$mtu\n";
}
```

`$balanced` is used once you have matched the opening `{` of a block, and goes on to match anything that is not `{` or `}` by using `[^{}]*`. This is optionally followed by `{`, the recursion going back 2 parentheses, and `}`, namely `{(?-2)*}`. This is inside `()?` to make it optional. I am not a perl expert, so there is undoubtably a more optimal version of this.